# How to remove /pages from url shopify?

Tags: shopify

I am working on shopify theme. And i want to remove /pages from some simple pages.I didnt't find any solution from shopify support or forum nor from google. How can I solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From speaking to Shopify support previously regarding this matter there is no way to remove /pages from the URL structure. You are only able to edit the end of the URL structure. Eg: /pages/**page-title**

The URL structure and how many sub folders you have has a minimal affect when it comes to SEO and doesn't impact ranking as much as backlinks or content quality.

I would recommend optimising your URLs by making sure your page name contains appropriate keywords and is easy to read.

Comment: Is this possible with proxy?

Comment: No, I don't believe there is any way to edit it. Apparently Shopify use the directory structure to define which layout is pulled. This is what support told me when I asked. Take a look at this response by a Shopify employee: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/not-seo-friendly-urls-343854

Answer (score 0):

In shopify community I found this:

```
POST /admin/redirects.json
  {
   "redirect": {
   "path": "/about-us",
   "target": "/pages/about-us"
  }
}
```

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Remove-Pages-from-URL-my-store/td-p/459907